# Always return 1 even when there is no table related object

Tags: mysql

I query my database for a table with joined related table
Example: I want to show all styles and join mixes with that style but show 0 mixes if thst style don't have mixes related.

Here is my 2 tables:

#### First The Mixes table

```
CREATE TABLE `mixes` (
  `mixes_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datePublic` date DEFAULT NULL ,
  `timeLenght` time DEFAULT NULL ,
  `Title` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'No-Title-Yet' ,
  `dwnlSize` varchar(45) DEFAULT '? MegaBytes',
  `Quality` char(10) DEFAULT '? kbits/s',
  `style_id` int(3) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `collection_id` int(3) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT '001',
  `lienDwnld` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VidLink` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArtisteFeat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slugMixTitle` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cache` enum('0','1') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mixes_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Title_UNIQUE` (`Title`),
  UNIQUE KEY `lienDwnld_UNIQUE` (`lienDwnld`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slugMixTitle` (`slugMixTitle`),
  KEY `style_index` (`style_id`),
  KEY `collection_index` (`collection_id`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

ALTER TABLE `mixes`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `collectionMustExist` FOREIGN KEY (`collection_id`) REFERENCES `collection` (`collection_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `styleMustExist` FOREIGN KEY (`style_id`) REFERENCES `style` (`style_id`);
```

#### Then the style Table

```
CREATE TABLE `style` (
  `style_id` int(3) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imgMixCat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nameMixCat` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descMixCat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slugMixCat` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hideMixCat` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`style_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nameMixCat_UNIQUE` (`nameMixCat`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slugMixCat` (`slugMixCat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

#### And this is my current Query:

```
SELECT 
  count(style.style_id) AS count,
  nameMixCat,
  style.style_id,
  descMixCat,
  hideMixCat,
  slugMixCat,
  imgMixCat
FROM style as style
LEFT JOIN mixes as mixes ON style.style_id = mixes.style_id
GROUP BY style.style_id
ORDER BY style.style_id ASC
```

So what make return 1 when there is no mixes related to a style?

Comment: You should use a `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. Checkout the differences between the two types of joins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: Ok I figure out where is my error ! I was counting styles in my _SELECT_ statement... Now I use **count(mixes.mixes_id) AS count** ...

Comment: `Length` is spelled this way not this way: `Lenght`

Comment: Because id's names are identical, how can I simplify query? Without tablename prepend?